# How to rename the .mcs output file when synthesizing a design with Xilinx ISE

Tags: xilinx-ise

When I synthesize a design using `Xilinx ISE`, the output file is named `untitled.mcs`. I would like to configure the project to use an output filename more appropriate to the project I am synthesizing.

I have examined all the properties easily reachable by right clicking the the implementation panel in the tool, but I can't find a configuration option to change output file names. I have also searched the help, but couldn't find anything useful. Can anyone suggest where I need to configure the output filename or tell me where or what to search?

I am aware of at least two things I could be doing wrong and would appreciate comments. First, I am not using `TCL` to synthesize my project. I just right click in the implementation panel and choose run. Perhaps if I create a `TCL` script to I would have finer control or output file naming. Second, I can see several files named `untitled.x` where `x` is `[cfi|mcs|prm|sig]`. I guess these are a sequence of files processed from one format to another, and if I understood the process, I could configure the name of the first and see all the derived files change their names to follow.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question is that you don't use ISE to configure output PROM file names, you do it in the iMPACT tool. When it is properly configured, ISE will run iMPACT to create the programming file.

If anyone needs the precise details on configuring iMPACT, the built in help has the details. See the section entitled "Creating Xilinx Flash/PROM Files". During the setup of the programming file, you get to choose the output file name.

One extra pointer from me: The help says you double click to open a wizard. For me that didn't work, but there is an icon (or tool bar button) to launch the PROM file formatter wizard when Create PROM File is highlighted in the iMPACT Flows panel.

When you have created an saved an iMPACT project file, you select it in ISE and ISE will create a PROM programming file at the last step of the synthesize process.